# Find all Ids & Classes from HTML files contents with PHP

Tags: php, html

In PHP I have a variable containing the HTML of one of my webpages, I am attempting to search this variable to pull out all ID's and Class's used within the file and put them within an Array. The PHP file doesn't have a log of the existing Classes or ID's so I can't just search each individual Class/ID using something like `strpos()`. The issue this then poses is I need to somehow find all mentions of `class="******"` without knowing the length before the last speech mark and the same for Id's

So I would end up with an array something like ...

```
    $array = array(
    "id" => array("id1","id2","id3"),
    "class" => array("class1","class2","class3"));
```

From my searching, I'm guessing I will need to use something like the following, but I could do with some help working out how to get it to work.

```
    //the variable containing the HTML content
    $page_content = $page_get->post_content;
    //the array to save the id's/class's into
    $matches = array();

    //from my understanding something like this would find the start being id=" 
    //then anything inbetween untill the end being "
    preg_match('id="(.*)"', $page_content, $matches);
```

This is for use in an admin end of the site for gathering ID's and classes used on the site in a page builder plugin. If it was front end I would be using Jquery and other methods of searching the DOM elements.

Comment: It sounds unusual that you would need to obtain all the ID's, so I would suggest rethinking if you really need to do that, and if there is a simpler way to achieve whatever it is that you need.
If however you really want to do this, I would suggest not doing this string search by yourself, but instead finding a library that will take your HTML and parse it DOM, making it easy for you to traverse it and obtain the ID's and classes. Quick search gives me this: https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of doing this would be to process it using DOM (here I'm using DOMDocument) and use XPath to extract all of the ID's and classes as the attributes of the document.

With the ID's it's just extracting all of the IDs and adding them to an array.  Classes has the extra part of using `explode()` to split the classes for any particular element into it's component classes...

```
$html = '<div id="aaa" class="a" /><div id="bb" class="a b c"><b id="g" /></div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$ids = $xp->query("//@id");
$idList = [];
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
    $idList[] = $id->nodeValue;
}

print_r($idList);

$ids = $xp->query("//@class");
$classList = [];
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
    $classList = array_merge($classList, explode(" ", $id->nodeValue));
}

print_r(array_unique($classList));
```

with the simple example HTML, this gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => aaa
    [1] => bb
    [2] => g
)
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
)
```

Comment: Cheers, @NigelRen that did exactly what I was after. A totally different angle to what I was thinking and makes a lot more sense